# Nemo / Nautilus folder icon size

Tags: nautilus, icons, source-code, thumbnails, nemo

Does anybody know how to reduce this white space - distance on nemo or nautilus between the folders? It's getting ridiculous! I've enlarged the thumbnails from dconf-editor and I also use compact mode, which seems kind of messy. The folders are tiny and have a lot of space between them.

In the attachment picture you see one folder takes all over the screen there's sure space for more! Can I edit the source code or something for the file manager, forcing it to use a bigger icons for the folders? Is there a better solution?!

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why, but the spacing behaves better when setting org>nemo>icon-view>labels-beside-icons to true in dconf-editor.

Comment: Nautilus 3.16 has this feature.

Comment: how can I update to 3.16 does it work with cinnamon?

Answer (score 1):

You need to zoom out.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Scroll</kbd> to zoom in and out, like you would do on a webpage.

You might also prefer listview - at the top click the icon that looks like this: <kbd>**≡**</kbd>. It will look like this instead:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying but zooming surely doesn't fix my problem. Is there something possible for icon view and without text besides icon , like a  normal folder thumbnail without unnecessary spacing.

Comment: Here's what folder besides folder looks like when zooming out. After this point they become tiny. There's space here enough to fit double of the folders
http://imgur.com/UAfzBXz

Comment: That seems to be as compact as they go.