# Nemo icon view spacing

Tags: nemo

I recently changed from Nautilus to Nemo because lacking of "type-ahead-search" and sorting in search.

Overall experience in Nemo is great except there's way to much space between icon in normal view.

Compact view make things so messy as it doesn't align anything. But the spacing looks fine.

Is there a way to change the spacing?

This is how it look like by default[image: This is how it look like now]

This is the compact view[image: This is the compact view]

This is what I think it should be[image: This is from nautilus]

There seems to be the exact same question 6 years ago but no answer [Nemo / Nautilus folder icon size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633751/nemo-nautilus-folder-icon-size)